# Google Analytics: Rewrite referral to a campaign

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to rewrite a referral to a campaign (campaign name) instead? I've got some problems with affiliates modifing links to my site and therefore this counts as referral traffic instead of campaign traffic. The only really important thing is the campaign name and the placement of the referral (in the campaign report section).

Is it possible to use a filter (search and replace or advanced) to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

there are a few options you can use.

1) see here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCampSourceKey

2) you can write some code to redirect a visitor who comes to your site from an affiliate to a url that has GA tracking

3) affiliate landing page links should keep the original structure that you send them. f they are modifying it you should contact the affiliate network you use. you might even be able to get away with not paying them because they are not using the links you are sending.